# One of the client says that is virus in my page and send me this picture

Tags: wordpress, mixed-content-security

Try to scan with several URL scanners no virus found, please advice

[image]

Comment: There's some general advice for infected sites in the linked threads. Aside from that it would be difficult to figure out the best course of action without doing an individual site review, which is off topic here.

Comment: As this is Wordpress related it may be a better fit over there.  I wonder if there is evidence of a compromise in your database.  I do observe that the hacked file was in wordpress fastest cache, so its possible something was temporarily injected.

Comment: `6aoig.js` - from the filename alone that looks dodgy!

Comment: @MrWhite well, minification can make names of things unreadable